# Is the gravitational pull of the early ($10^{10}$ more massive) universe still observable?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, universe, gravitational-waves, baryogenesis

During one of the early epochs of the universe it used to be 10^10 times more massive than it is now, just before the matter / antimatter annihilation.  So what cosmic gravity is being asserted on the galaxies we observe?  Is it the gravity of the early universe or the gravity of the current universe?  There was hyperinflation, and the universe expands faster than the speed of light.  So is the 1 part in 10^10 gravity still rippling outward behind some enormous gravitational waves?

Also in general the universe is losing mass as matter turns into energy.  Is there some lag whereby the gravity exerted in some places in greater than the current mass of the objects exerting the gravity?

Comment: Just some thoughts: gravity is coupled to energy, not mass; energy doesn't change upon annohilation; gravitational signatures of the early universe are being actively searched.

Comment: Can someone help me choose an answer to accept.  Please up vote the answers.  I have no way of knowing which is dos correct, so please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

While the universe was much more massive back then, it was also much more uniform, meaning that the net gravitational attraction probably is essentially zero.

Comment: After reading the other answers, I agree that mass-energy equivalence makes this a moot point. I leave this answer here to demonstrate that it doesn't matter even assuming Newtonian gravity.

Answer (score 0):

@Solenodon is correct. The $10^{10}$ particle antiparticle pairs became radiation. The gravitational effect is accounted for in the FLRW cosmological model, with the percent of the matter-energy density by radiation then being nearly 100%. It is now about 0%, with matter about 25% and dark energy about 75%.

It's accounted for in the cosmological solution, with different periods in which the velocity and acceleration of the universe varied some depending on what the matter-density was comprised of.

That rippling out happened very early, and whefon matter antimatter annihilated photons became preponderant. The temperature was too high and photons scattered of charged particles, and everything was ionized. After the temperature went down to about 4000K protons and electrons combined and the light was able to escape. That light we see now as the cosmic microwave background. So, yes, the ripple effect is that CMB.

And the gravitational effect of matter turning into radiation or some of the other changes in the history just changed slightly for a period of time the velocity and acceleration of the universe.

See the history of the universe at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe

You can see the different epochs and things that happened. The recombination epoch is when the CMB was let loose

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that we can talk of an early universe is because of [General Relativity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) The the Big Bang model , on which your terminology is based is primarily dependent on General relativity for formation and boundary conditions until nucleosynthesis .  General Relativity does not know "mass" in its mathematical formulation, just the [stress-energy tensor.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#In_general_relativity_2).

It is only in classical mechanics and Newtonian physics that mass is an additive concept. For special  relativity it is the [four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) that are added and masses of particles are not additive. In general relativity, locally the same is true. Even conservation of energy is a concept applied locally to flat spaces, i.e. where the curvature induced by GR is negligible.

After nucleosynthesis and certainly after the decoupling of radiation at 380.000 years from the Big Bang conservation of mass holds locally when velocities of objects are much smaller than the velocity of light , and four vectors are unnecessary .

So no, the universe locally is not loosing mass. The gravitational effect of the present masses gets smaller because of the continuing expansion of the universe.

> So is the 1 part in 10^10 gravity still rippling outward behind some enormous gravitational waves?

The adverb "still" defines a time. We exist at a time t, now. All the ripples and stuff happened and are [modeled by the BB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)). That is all. The still is in the still picture:

[image: history]

We are at the vertical plane in this picture on the edge on the right, at the time t0. No interaction with the past.